# How can I securely fetch and pass data to all pages using getServerSideProps or middleware in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, middleware, react-context

Can you tell me please, I need to fetch some data (nextjs) on the server side through `getServerSideProps` or middleware (to protect API key) and then the received data pass by props or context or something else to all pages. At the moment I get data with context on client side, but all tokens, secrets API is public, I need to hide it. What is the best way to do it?

I tried with middleware, but I don't understand how to pass received data by props. Also `getServerSideProps` works well, but only for one page but I need use the data everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible, and yes: You can still make the request on the client side if you want to pass it to a context store. You and make your request containing your secret there.

##### Example

Create a folder called `api` inside your `pages` directory. The file structure works the same as in the pages directory itself.

Assuming you wanted to create an API available at `/api/my-api` you would create the file `/pages/api/my-api.ts`.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const response = await fetch("https://example.com/my-api-endpoint", {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.VERY_SECRET_KEY}` },
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  res.status(200).json(data);
}

export default handler;
```

Then instead of calling your api directly from the client side you call the api you just created instead, this way your secrets only remain on the server at all times.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give an example how to return the result as response for that API endpoint and how to request the local API on the client side. I'm new at this.

Comment: I can update my original answer with an example, of course. But I would have to know what next version you are using and if you are using the pages or app directory.

Comment: nextjs - 13.4.3, use the pages

Comment: @Xaero I have updated the original answer with an example for you.

Comment: Thanks. Last question, how can i call just created the api in client side? For example call data in my AppContext.

Comment: Just execute a fetch request to the endpoint, like you would any other API.